Configuring Internal Load Balancer for Charmed Kubeflow on AKS
I’m in the process of setting up Charmed Kubeflow on AKS for evaluation, and I ran into an issue during the Juju controller bootstrap. By default, the bootstrap process creates a public load balancer for the controller service. However, in my use case, I need this to be an internal load balancer for security and routing reasons.
I’ve gone through the documentation but haven’t been able to find the appropriate configuration flag to pass in the juju bootstrap command to make the load balancer internal.
Has anyone encountered this issue or knows how to set up the controller with an internal load balancer? Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance for your help!

why are you asking this here?

@graham It's on topic here.

ubuntu relevance? Distro/version?
